# Unwanted <Style> Tag generated by wp_footer()

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to identify where a `<style>` tag is being generated from within my wordpress twentytwenty theme footer.

Within footer.php it's clear that the style tag is generated by the `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` call.

Upon inspection of the footer on the frontend, there is a style element that I don't want. It looks like this:

```
//hardcoded footer
<style>
    #site-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
    }
</style>
// more dynamically generated content that I need.
```

I know that you can remove these styles with `wp_dequeue_style()` or with `remove_action()` but I have absolutely no clue what handle to use to identify it.
It doesn't have an id, or a class, so i'm not sure how to target it and remove it.

It's causing some unwanted effects on the rest of my page that need to be fixed. I could of course rename my ID site-content, but that's undesirable.

I've been searching through my files to try to identify which plugin or theme file could be adding this, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like in the following examples (edit the css values from setProperty for your needs). The first two examples add inline css to the desired element(s). Inline styles have highest priority. The last example adds the same rule, but with modified properties, to the end of the page. Place the example you want to try in the theme's functions.php.

For an element with a certain id:

```
function javascript_to_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            $( '#site-content' )[0].style.setProperty( 'overflow', 'hidden', 'important' );
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'javascript_to_footer' );
```

For elements with a certain class:

```
function javascript_to_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            $( '.some-content' ).each( function() {
                this.style.setProperty( 'overflow', 'hidden', 'important' );
            } );
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'javascript_to_footer' );
```

What else you could try, depending on where your mentioned rule is placed in the code this may or may not work:

```
function css_to_footer() {
    ?>
    <style>
        #site-content {
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'css_to_footer' );
```

Comment: Yes this is definitely a solution. However, it doesn't seem to get to the root of the issue. Is there any way to find where that style is being added and remove it?